# Why is command tilde/acute not working?

Tags: osx-lion

It's clear that my hot key is enabled and I even reset it to <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>~/`</kbd> (tilde/acute key), but it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm assuming you reset the keyboard shortcut under System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts.  Is this correct?  What did you set it to and what are you expecting it to do--the default "move to next application window"?

Comment: Yes to everything.

Comment: Okay.  One more question:  Did you happen to set assign this keyboard shortcut to something else somewhere along the way?

Comment: Are you using Witch, Butler, Alfred, Launchbar, Quicksilver, FastScripts, TextExpander, or any other practically invisible background program that supports triggering program functionality using hotkeys? Does it work when you quit these programs?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue. I am seeing the same behavior , it did not work even after quitting launchbar and other such programs and reset all shortcuts to defaults

Comment: @harijay No, I didn't

Answer (score 12):

The fix is to goto keyboard shortcut preferences and tick the option 'move focus to next window' under 'keyboard' section.
Thanks [fix cmd backtick](https://superuser.com/questions/186863/command-backtick-isnt-working-to-cycle-through-windows-in-some-apps-including)

Comment: A had this option already enabled, but undo and apply the checkbox again fix it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Have the same problem. In my case problem is in the keyboard settings: `§` shown then I press `` ` `` on my keyboard. This is because of I choose `ISO (European)` in `System settings -> Keyboard -> Change keyboard type` wizard. Just change it to `ANSI (USA and others)` and `` ` `` returns.

If you need keep `ISO (European)` just reassign shortcut `move focus to next window` to `command`-`§` (find shortcut, click on existing key combination and press on keyboard `command`-`§`/`` ` ``).

Comment: I was using a bluetooth keyboard (Keychron K2) which needed a firmware update.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, brilliant

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and it looks like if the Chrome is maximized, <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>~/`</kbd> (tilde/acute key) doesn’t work to shift between windows of Chrome.

So I tried minimizing, but expanded the window size manually, switching windows between Chrome work with this. So do not maximize the window.

Answer (score 2):

A sure fire way to get that working again (barring something strange) is to restore the default keyboard shortcuts.

Visit System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts and smack the "Restore Defaults" button.

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Another potential cause of this problem is if you have changed your keyboard language. I use two different languages and it changes the location of the tilde key.

Change your keyboard back to normal language or use the key location of tilde in whatever keyboard you're using.