# Command–Grave accent (⌘`) not switching between Safari 17 windows on mac OS Sonoma

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, safari

On Safari 17 (mac OS Sonoma) the Command–Grave accent (`⌘`+`` ` ``) is not switching between Safari windows. It works fine on every other app, except for Safari. I've tested on two different Macs and I see the same behaviour. It even works if I'm on the Safari Settings window, onto a browser window, but then it gets stuck.

I have the "Move focus to next window" active with the `⌘`+`` ` `` key combination on System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Keyboard.

- I've tried what's described here [Command Backtick isn't working to cycle through windows in some apps (including Safari)](https://superuser.com/questions/186863/command-backtick-isnt-working-to-cycle-through-windows-in-some-apps-including?noredirect=1&lq=1), but nothing worked.
- I've tested replacing the normal keyboard shortcut `⌘`+`` ` `` by `Shift`+`⌘`+`` ` `` and then the correct behaviour happens – it switches between Safari Windows. So it seems something is capturing that shortcut specifically whenever I'm on a Safari Window (but not the Safari Settings window).
- I've also disabled (and then removed) all Safari extensions, and `⌘`+`` ` `` continues to not work. Deleted multiple caches and leftover plugins from bygone eras.
- I've also disabled Safari's usage of iCloud (as I've seen this behaviour on my two Macs), but to no avail.
- I've booted into safe mode, but again `⌘`+`` ` `` still does not toggle between open Safari windows, suggesting its not a login item.
- It happens both with the laptop's (US) internal keyboard, or with external ones.

I'm at a loss at whatever is capturing `⌘`+`` ` `` on Safari. This did not happen before I updated to mac OS Sonoma.

Any ideias on how to track it down? (or, better yet, how solve it?)

Comment: Are all windows in the same Space? It's never worked between Spaces [or with fullscreen].

Comment: Yep. Single Space/Desktop, and no fullscreen windows.

Comment: Ah, OK. It's not something i can test, sorry. Wish you luck.

Comment: Some discussion here: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/16zpjau/sonoma_move_focus_to_next_window_not_working/

Comment: Thanks @k4rtik, seems some people reported a bug with Stage Manager, and alas, if I turn stage manager on, it does ⌘+` works on Safari windows... so an Apple Bug.

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't changed the combination, like you mention in second bullet, but the combination Shift + command + ` workning to me without do something.